# How can I loop back to the first callback function of jquery load, after a dynamically loaded form is submitted?

Tags: jquery, forms, callback, load

I DELETED ORIGINAL STATEMENT TO SHOW SOMETHING USEFULL :

Index.html has a button which when clicked loads a form from whatever.html into #content div.

In order for my form to work and reload the page correctly, I have to rerwrite the code to match the idea behind the correct answer.

I still want to state that : 
**If this is not how it should be done, dont bother trying to make this code work and please point me torwards the good direction, this has to be dynamic though.**

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#nav').on('click', 'button', function() {
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    loadContent(name);
})

function loadContent(button) {
    $('#content').empty();
    $('#content').load(name + ' #content > *');
}

$('#content').on('submit', function(event) {        
    event.preventDefault();
    var divid = $(this).attr('id');
    ajForm(divid);
    console.log(divid);
    $('#content').empty();
    $('#content').load('form.html #content > *');
})

function ajForm(divid){ // id = form_id, result=destination_div
    var data = $('#' + divid + ' > *').serialize(); 
    console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: data,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#result').html('loading...');
                },
            success:function(data){
                $('#result').empty();
                $('#result').append(data);
                },
            error:function(){
                $('#result').html('fuck me');
                }
            }); 
}; // ajaxForm
```

}); //$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need simply to delegate form submission to a suitable ancestor element in the same way you already delegate button click events.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#hn-nav').on('click', 'button', loadFormsAndDatabaseContent)
    $('#main-content').on('submit', 'form', reloadMainContent);

    function loadFormsAndDatabaseContent(event) {
        ...
    }
    function reloadMainContent (event) {
        ...
    }
});
```

The code in the two functions will be some extract/modification of the code you have already tried.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to make sure I understand your logic well enough, I should put an event listner on the main-content (the div that is in both pages) thatll launch the form. Ill try to work on that and comment.

Comment: Not quite. The listener is placed on the main-content but will respond to submission of any form contained within it.

Comment: I don't understand "both pages". The question indicates that everything happens within one page.

Comment: Well the index.php and the dynamic loaded page share a #main-content section to make things simpler to sort. I understand what Roamer means, im trying to make it work on a test page. Thanks again for the help, ill let you know.